# Fetch the user details who is browsing the website

Tags: asp.net, ldap

i have written a code which I thought should ideally fetch the current user accessing the website. However it displays console ID of the server where the page is hosted.  Below is the code.. need suggestions.

the code is fetching the user details from LDAP.

please let me know if i need to provide more details

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace UserDetail
{
    public partial class UserDet : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public DirectorySearcher dirSearch = null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string username = Environment.UserName; //Or you put your username if you have any one
            //string pswd = "test";   //Provide paassword to login  to LDAP
            //string domain = Environment.UserDomainName;     //Provide Domain Name your own

            string username = "test";  //Username for Authentication
            string pswd = "test";       // password for Authentication
            string domain = "abc.com";     // Provide Domain name

            // GetUserInformation(username,pswd,domain);
            Label1.Text = Environment.UserName.ToString();
        }
        public void GetUserInformation(string username, string passowrd, string domain)
        {
            string searchUsername = Environment.UserName;      //Provide username to be search
            SearchResult rs = null;
            rs = SearchUserByUserName(GetDirectorySearcher(username, passowrd, domain), searchUsername);

            if (rs != null)
            {
                if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
                    Label1.Text = "Username : " + rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        public SearchResult SearchUserByUserName(DirectorySearcher ds, string username)
        {
            ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + username + "))";

            ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

            SearchResult userObject = ds.FindOne();

            if (userObject != null)
                return userObject;
            else
                return null;
        }
        public DirectorySearcher GetDirectorySearcher(string username, string passowrd, string domain)
        {

            try
            {
                var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain); // Without authentication
                //var de= new new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, username, passowrd);   // With authentication
                dirSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);

            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
            {
                Label1.Text=  e.Message.ToString();
            }
            return dirSearch;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  the below code to get the username of windows logged in user.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Tostring()
```

Comment: can you show me where should I put this piece of line... is it here.
 Label1.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Tostring();
        }

Comment: Replace  `Environment.UserName.ToString();`  with `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Tostring();`

Comment: Hi Gagan Deep , it  still shows the  ID of the server...  it should show the user ID of the user accessing the website.. Can you please help again,

Comment: Have you set the authentication mode to Windows in web.config?

Comment: <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
      </system.web>

this way ?